# Word or phrase for clicking and ignoring

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, computing

I am looking for a word or phrase that is used to describe when people using mobile applications (or desktop applications or websites) do not fully read some prompt/warning/error message and simply click the ok/ignore button.

Comment: I’ve heard this described with a phrasal verb: “clicking through the acceptance screens”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called **[popup blindness](https://optinmonster.com/6-reasons-pop-ups-welcome-gates-and-slide-ins-suck-and-the-solution/)**:

> If they’ve been around the Internet for a while, it’s also possible that they’ve developed “popup blindness”.
>
> That means they’ve conditioned themselves to ignore the popup or welcome gate entirely and to click out of it as quickly as they can. The result may just be a minor annoyance for the visitor, but it still does nothing for you, the business owner who wants to drive conversions on their site.

(Ironically, while browsing the site I found this quote on, I was presented with two pop ups, both of which I yeeted off my screen as fast as I could.)

Answer (score 1):

**They don’t read the fine print.**

Any example of this term used in a article about click-to-agree in websites at [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2017/mar/03/terms-of-service-online-contracts-fine-print) begins:

> Apparently losing rights to data and legal recourse is not enough of a reason to inspect online contracts. So how can websites get users **to read the fine print**?

Actually as the article says they often don’t even **look** at the fine print let alone read it!